# which is the best method to poll for a variable [C/Linux]

Tags: c, linux

I have to check if a variable is changed from a database(custom) every second using C/Linux. I would like to know the methods available for polling a variable in C/Linux. Thanks

Comment: What interface does your database provide ? Can it be accessed by shell ?

Comment: Polling is bad option in my opinion. Hook the interface that reads/writes the data you want to poll, so that whenever read/write occurs, based on your situation, you can trigger something.

Comment: Database provides me a set of API's like DB_get_value(handle,path,value) . I would liek to do this from a C program.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to implement `DB_get_value` API ?

Comment: The Interface is provided by the Database vendor , I have to call it in order to get the value.

Comment: Is there any interface which can notify the system when value changed